# How to pass command line arguments in deno test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, deno

For example:

```
Deno.test({
  name: "Testing qr-html generation",
  fn: async () => {
    await createQRhtml();
    assertEquals(exists("out/qr.html"), true);
  }
});
```

`createQRhtml()` function takes arguments from command line. Specifically, first argument: `Deno.args[0]`.

How to specify here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your CLI arguments after a double dash (`--`) like this:

```
deno test args.test.ts -- hello
```

`args.test.ts`:

```ts
import {assert} from 'https://deno.land/std@0.109.0/testing/asserts.ts';

function isHello (str?: unknown): boolean {
  return str === 'hello';
}

Deno.test('First CLI argument is "hello"', () => {
  const [firstArg] = Deno.args;
  assert(isHello(firstArg));
});
```

You can learn about the `test` commmand and other commands in your CLI using the form:

```
deno help COMMAND_NAME
```

This is included in the output of `deno help test`:

```
USAGE:
    deno test [OPTIONS] [files]... [-- <SCRIPT_ARG>...]
```

See also: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/8096